# Setting UILabel text not working?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have this XML parser class that needs to set the text of a UILabel. For some reason when I call my external (My external custom method is located in ViewController) custom method from the XML parsing class I cant change the labels text. Anything else like NSLogging works or an UIAlert works.
Code im trying to do it with:

**XML Parsing class**

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"names"]){
        NSLog(@"Found names body");

    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"user"]){

 array = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"nameofuser"];
        ViewController * main = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [main outputToLabel:array];

    }
    NSLog(@"Reading value: %@", elementName);
}
```

This is my ViewController custom method:

```
-(void) outputToLabel:(NSArray *) dict{

    NSLog(@"seting %@ srcds", dict);
    // XML stuff here \/

NSLog(@"%@", dict);

       //                 /\

    this.text = @"Complete";
}
```

It NSLogs out the values correctly and everything... I just cant set the labels text. I can use that code in viewDidLoad and it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
    ViewController * main = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [main outputToLabel:array];
```

You're creating a new instance of your ViewController and setting the label in it.  The "real" instance of ViewController is not affected by this action.

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer - Think about it.  You've got an object over there that is the one that's being shown on the screen.  Creating a new object over here does no good.  You've got to somehow get the address of the object over there -- pass it in as a parameter, access it as a global variable, et.  Search here for "how do I pass a parameter between view controllers" and similar questions and you will find that this is an incredibly common (and boring) question (and one that even a modestly skilled programmer would not need to ask).